# How to generate a pie chart from geo_points within a geo_shape in ELK?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, elasticsearch-geo-shape

ELK stack newbie here. I have created a map by importing GEOJSON data in KIBANA.

The data is indexed as geo_shape and it contains the World's territorial waters area. It represents a layer in my map. I have then added another layer, always using GEOJSON, containing geo_points representing the gps data of a yacht charter:

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE0v5.jpg)

Now, in my dashboard, I would like to show a pie chart, indicating the percentage of time spent by the yacht during this charter outside of the territorial waters, but I am unable to understand how to do that.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share a sample of the yacht data? How's it structured?

Comment: Thanks @JoeSorocin ! Sure, you can see the GEOJSON file here: http://84.33.95.3:81/tatiana_charter.geojson  I generated it from a CSV file

Comment: Here you can see the territorial waters GEOJSON: http://84.33.95.3:81/eez_12nm.json

Comment: OK The first problem I see is that you don't have unique IDs for your yachts in the charter geojson. How exactly would you want to identify the yachts?

Comment: I was thinking to use the geo_shape created by the territorial waters as boundaries, then I would add a layer for each charter trip and I need to output the percentage of time spent outside of the boundaries for VAT calculation purposes, I do not really need to know the yacht's name, but rather how much time a single boat has spent outside of territorial waters (in percentage)

Comment: I hear ya but don't see any indication of `M/Y TATIANA I` or similar. Are you sure it's in there?

Comment: No, it's not in there, as I will create a new geojson for each yacht, or at least each charter. I think I have the wrong approach, but my intention is to generate a pie chart that shows the percentage of time spent outside of the territorial waters for every charter trip. In my dashboard, ideally, I have the map and the pie chart. Later (once I learn how to do it...), I will add a secondary chart showing the time spent in each individual territorial waters area (i.e.: french 12 nm, italian 12 nm, etc)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'll need a time series dataset -- either each yacht geo point sending a position signal every couple of minutes or a collection of different positions with durations of stay at any given point. Only then can you generate those duration/intersection pie charts. Generally speaking, the community here will need a minimum reproducible example in order to help you. Discussions like these should happen *before* posting a question here :)

Comment: Sorry about that... Basically, I have the dates in the geojson file, what I would like to do is to merge the geo_points data with the geo_shape boundaries

Comment: That's fine but in order for you to compare the times the vessels stayed in the territorial waters, you'll need multiple geojson points withe the same IDs but different positions and dates...

Comment: Thanks, I will look in that direction. Meanwhile I try to create a pie chart using filters.

Comment: Sounds good. Good luck!